# clang vs gcc CRTP: constexpr variable cannot have non-literal type

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, constexpr, crtp

I have a CRTP template class here:

```
template <typename S>
class Base
{
    public:
    constexpr static S NOT_SET{0};
};

struct Derived : public Base<Derived>
{
};
```

Clang (5.0.0) does not accept this:

```
5 : <source>:5:24: error: constexpr variable cannot have non-literal type 'const Derived'
    constexpr static S NOT_SET{0};
                       ^
8 : <source>:8:25: note: in instantiation of template class 'Base<Derived>' requested here
struct Derived : public Base<Derived>
                        ^
5 : <source>:5:24: note: incomplete type 'const Derived' is not a literal type
    constexpr static S NOT_SET{0};
                       ^
8 : <source>:8:8: note: definition of 'Derived' is not complete until the closing '}'
struct Derived : public Base<Derived>
       ^
1 error generated.
Compiler exited with result code 1
```

But gcc (tested on 4.9.2 and 6.2) accepts it just fine.

How does one go about doing this in clang?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Derived` isn't a complete type when you try to use it in the class template `Base`, so you cannot actually use it that way. That's because a type must be complete to be able to declare a variable of that type. No way to work around it.
To sum up, a type is complete at the closing `}` (and other exceptions that are irrelevant for your case, like within its member functions).
This is what the standard says ([working draft](http://eel.is/c++draft/class#mem-6)):

> A class is considered a completely-defined object type (or complete type) at the closing } of the class-specifier.
>   Within the class member-specification, the class is regarded as complete within function bodies, default arguments, noexcept-specifiers, and default member initializers (including such things in nested classes).
>   Otherwise it is regarded as incomplete within its own class member-specification.

Therefore clang is right and the error says more or less the same.

---

As mentioned in the comments, a way to work around it exists. As long as the derived type is (let me say) *constexpr constructible*, you can define a constexpr function in the base class that returns you its *not set* version (whatever it means).

Comment: Thanks: however if I'm trying to port an existing codebase, which exploits this "feature" of GCC, to clang, what would your advice be?

Comment: As long as the derived type is constexpr constructible, you can define a constexpr function in the base class that returns you its _not set_ version (whatever it means). Could it work for you?

Comment: Yes, it's a good idea. Thank you. I'll accept your answer, but do you reckon you could put your comment into the answer too, for posterity? :-)

Comment: @Anton Done. Thank you.